# python: imported module is in a different context

Tags: python, variables, import, module

I'm trying to modify a variable in a different module. The modifier method is also in that module. Apparently the context changes and the modification does not persist.

### Test1.py

```
from Test2 import *

function()
print var
```

### Test2.py

```
var = 0

def function():
    global var
    var = 1
```

If I execute Test1.py the result is always 0 even though the function has been executed.

Two ways to fix this are:

1. to import things again after calling the function
2. to replace the import sentence by "import Test2" and add the path to any call to Test2.

These solutions work but I would like to understand why this is happening, why the context does not mix varibles if they have been imported.

Comment: This won't work, because you created a new reference `var` in `Test1` that is not updated when `Test2.var` is rebound. Don't use `from module import *` but use `import module` instead so you continue to use the same reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing from another module is a lot like assignment, and your `var` variable in `Test1` is not assigned to when `var` in `Test2` is assigned to.

The expression `from Test2 import *` does this under the hood:

- Load the `Test2.py` file if not yet loaded, creating the `sys.modules['Test2']` module object. If that object already exists this step is skipped.
- List all public attributes on the `sys.modules['Test2']` module object. Public names are anything that doesn't start with `_`. If there is a `__all__` attribute.
- Add names in the current namespace bound to those objects:

  ```
  var = sys.modules['Test2'].var
  function = sys.modules['Test2'].function
  ```

Note that those are *new assignments*, to the `sys.modules['Test1']` or `sys.modules['**main**'] module.

Assigning to the `var` global within `Test2` then only sets `sys.modules['Test2'].var`, in the same way that

```
var = 1
var2 = var
var = 2
```

will not alter `var2`.

On the other hand, if you only import the `Test2` module as a global with

```
import Test2
```

then you are really asking Python to use `Test2 = sys.modules['Test2']`, and from there on out `Test2.var` is referencing the *same variable* as `var` inside the `Test2` module. This works the same way as if you had done this:

```
class Test2:
    var = 0

    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        cls.var = 1

test2 = Test2()
test2.method()
print(test2.var)
```